# Protection diodes

Tags: power-supply, motor, diodes

What are the rules when placing protection diodes into a power supply schematic?
More exactly, I have the attached schematic and I placed the protection diodes (D2, D3, D4 all of them 1N4007). Those protection diodes are for the protection of the power supply when I power inductive loads, for example motors.
[image: schematic]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Motors and inductive loads can push current **into** the supply, when that happens D2 and D3 limit the voltage across Q1 and U1 to prevent damage. Q1 already has a build-in diode but an extra one does no harm. The motor current will now charge the input capacitors. As long as that does not make the voltage increase beyond what the components can handle, that should also cause no harm.

An inductive load can also **force** a current in the "normal" direction but instead of the supply delivering the current the load delivers the current. D4 will conduct this current.

Your schematic takes care of currents generated by the motor for both directions so I think you did what is needed to protect the circuit under most circumstances.

Comment: How to calculate the minimum amperage of the protection diodes ? @Bimpelrekkie

Comment: Depends on the load, the motor or inductance. Unless you know how much current it can "push back" any value is a wild guess. Then in practice the 1N4007 diodes you suggest will do fine. Although rated for 1 A they can handle a short burst of current of a much higher value.

Comment: What about this schematic: [img]https://i.imgur.com/RIYLgco.png[/img] Are the protection diodes, especially D3, correctly placed in the schematic ? @Bimpelrekkie

Comment: Yes, I think they are. A choice could also be to connect the left side of D3 directly to the smoothing caps (C1, C2) like D2 but it will not make much difference. It is good as it is.